# Why does List<T>.Sort() where T:IComparable<T> produce a different order than List<T>.Sort(IComparer<T>)?

Tags: c#, list, sorting

`List<T>.Sort()` where `T:IComparable<T>` produces a different order than `List<T>.Sort(IComparer<T>)`, with equal inputs.

**Note the comparer is not really correct - it does not return 0 for equality.**

Both orders are valid (because the difference lies in the equal elements), but I'm wondering where the difference arises from, having looked through the source, and if it is possible to alter the IComparable.CompareTo to match the behavior of the IComparer.Compare when passed into the list.

The reason I'm looking at this is because IComparable is far faster than using an IComparer (which I'm guessing is why there are two different implementations in .NET), and I was hoping to improve the performance of an open source library by switching the IComparer to IComparable.

A full example is at: https://dotnetfiddle.net/b7s6my

Here's the class/comparer:

```
public class Point : IComparable<Point>
{
   public int X { get; }
   public int Y { get; }
   public int UID { get; set; } //Set by outside code
    
   public Point(int x, int y)
   {
      X = x;
      Y = y;
   }
    
   public int CompareTo(Point b)
   {
      return PointComparer.Default.Compare(this, b);
   }
}
public class PointComparer : IComparer<Point>
{
   public readonly static PointComparer Default = new PointComparer();
                
   public int Compare(Point a, Point b)
   {
       if (a.Y == b.Y)
       {
          return (a.X < b.X) ? -1 : 1;
       }
       return (a.Y > b.Y) ? -1 : 1;
   }
}
```

Note the comparer is not mine (so I can't really change it) - and changing the sort order causes the surrounding code to fail.

Comment: Well apart from anything else, the comparer is broken. For equal points, it doesn't return 0.  I don't know whether anything else is going on, but while the comparer is broken, all bets are off.

Comment: Given that `X` and `Y` are `int`, you should be using `int.CompareTo`. Compare the `Y` values first and, if the result is zero, compare the `X` values. That will address the issue mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: Dunno if you found this already, but [this](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/ArraySortHelper.cs,284) is where the branch of the two implementations happens.

Comment: Jon Skeet is right. If you fix your comparer to `var xCmp = a.X.CompareTo(b.X); return xCmp != 0 ? xCmp : a.Y.CompareTo(b.Y);` the code will produce the expected result.

Comment: Do you have one of your comparisons backwards? You have `a.X < b.X` but `a.Y > b.Y`. Should they both be using `<`?

Comment: Thanks guys - it looks like fixing the comparer does fix the difference, and does not break the library (ClipperLib). Why the two implementations of Sort yield different outcomes is an open question as they are clearly written using the same algorithm. (see System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper<T> vs. System.Collections.Generic.GenericArraySortHelper<T>)... albeit one that perhaps is not very important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments problem is with `IComparer<Point>`, which for two equal objects `a` and `b` (ones that have same `X` and `Y`) returns `Compare(a, b) = 1`, and `Compare(b, a) = 1`.

However, question arose why are the sorts still different.

Checking source of `ArraySortHelper` (see comment of @Sweeper) showed two versions of quick sort algorithm implementations (one of explicit `IComparer` and one for implicit).

Algorithms are mostly the same, however, function `PickPivotAndPartition` is a bit different. One function is `PickPivotAndParition(Span<T> keys)`, another is `PickPivotAndPartition(Span<T> keys, Comparison<T> comparer)`.

In first function there's line:

```cs
while (... && GreaterThan(ref pivot, ref leftRef = ref Unsafe.Add(ref leftRef, 1))) ;
```

And in second function similar line looks like:

```cs
while (comparer(keys[++left], pivot) < 0) ;
```

So, that looks to be a point - first function line can be thought as `Compare(pivot, left) > 0`, while second line as `Compare(left, pivot) < 0`, so when you have `Compare(left, pivot) = 1` and `Compare(pivot, left) = 1`, condition in first function will be true, while in second - false.

This means that two algorithm implementations can select different array slices and hence have different output.